# When moving a circle on a grid coordinates do not update as the picture does

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

This program is meant to create movable circles and show the coordinates of the circle that is moving. the problem is that the Xco value increments by ten when the circle is moved up or down using the keys despite the coordinates it's based on not changing.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    root = Tk()
    
    canvas_width = 1000
    canvas_height = 1000
    w = canvas_width // 2
    h = canvas_height // 2
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
    canvas.grid()
    
    r1 = canvas.create_oval(800, 800,  900,  900)
    r2 = canvas.create_oval(400, 400,  500,  500)
    r3 = canvas.create_oval(400, 400,  500,  500)
    t = canvas.create_text(20, 10, text="Hello")
    actionBtn = Button(root, text="Enter", width=10, height=1, command=quit).place(x=900, y=100) 
     
    def keypress(event): 
        
        gong = canvas.coords(r1)
        if all(i >= 0 for i in gong) and all(i <= 1000 for i in gong):
            print(canvas.coords(r1))
            
            x, y = 0, 0
            if event.char == "a" and gong[0] >= 10:
                x = -10
            if event.char == "d" and gong[2] <= 990:
                x = 10
            if event.char == "w" and gong[1] >= 10:
                y = -10
            if event.char == "s" and gong[3] <= 990:
                y = 10
            canvas.move(r1, x, y)
            Xco = str((gong[0]+gong[2])//2)
            structurelbl= Label(root, text= "X: "+Xco, width=10, height=1).place(x=900, y=100)
           # canvas.move(t, x, y)
                   
    root.bind("<Key>", keypress)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: change `r1 = canvas.create_oval(800, 800,  900,  900)` to `r1 = canvas.create_oval(400, 400,  500,  500)` and comment out r2 and r3 it works

Comment: I still have the same issue with that change . The program needs to work with a minimum of 3 circles also.

Comment: But in your code, only `r1 ` is moving and you are reading the coordinate of `r1` only then how can you expect to move all circles and capture their co-ordinates? e

Comment: This makes no sense: _"the problem is that the Xco value increments by ten ...despite the coordinates it's based on not changing."_ - you are clearly moving `r1` and then updating the label based on `r1`. It all seems to be behaving exactly as you want.

Comment: You need to call `gong = canvas.coords(r1)` again before setting `Xco`.  If you don't, `Xco` will be using the old coordinates before the move.

Comment: Ah thank you thats the one cheers.